# “sh -c 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches” - Permission denied

Tags: permissions, cron

I have a user with the same privilleges as root. When I run

```
sh -c 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
```

which is intended to run as `cron` I get : "Permission denied".

Comment: A user with the same privileges as root? This means you have a second root user?

Comment: i did this "sudo gpasswd -a user_remote wheel" and in sudoers file user_remote "ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL"

Comment: This means you still need to prefix your magic with `sudo` and then it will ask you for a password. To solve the interactive problem you can replace the last `ALL` with `NOPASSWD:ALL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a script to drop the caches and then allow `user_remote` to run it as root without a password.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

save as, e.g. `/usr/local/sbin/drop-caches.sh` and make it executable with:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/drop-caches.sh
```

Then add the following to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
user_remote ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/drop-caches.sh
```

"user_remote" can then run `sudo /usr/local/sbin/drop-caches.sh` from either their shell or from `cron` (or from anything else that allows them to execute a program).

Comment: i  thnik the problem was with the execute permission of the sh file i did this chmod +x file_name and it worked manually.i'm gonna program the sh as cron and wait for the result

Comment: yes, i thought it was obvious that I meant "run `chmod +x` with the script's name as the argument". I guess I was just being lazy and didn't want to type or paste the filename again.

Comment: thanks a lot that did the trick :D